# Converter return value not used

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to convert a value on my view model to the type that a control needs.  I have an `IValueConverter` implementation that **is** being called.  It **is** returning a valid value.  However, the value that is returned to the control is not what's returned by the converter.

> **NOTE** Below is a rough example, though not exactly my scenario.  I can't post my code as it belongs to the company.  Also, I've been unable to replicate the problem.  The same scenario in another application works fine.

My converter:

```
public class TupleCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var members = (IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>) value;
        var retVal = new ObservableCollection<string>(members.SelectMany(t => new[] {t.Item1, t.Item2}));
        return retVal;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ValuePairs, Converter={StaticResource MyTupleCollectionConverter}}"/>
```

When I debug, putting a break point at the return of the converter, I see that it's converting correctly with values, but then I get nothing in the control.  Running Snoop, it says that the `ItemsSource` property is set to null.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting your ItemsSource binding to two way and also adding the UpdateSourceTrigger setting to be PropertyChanged?

Comment: @Danielle, yes.  I've tried all variations.  No change.

Comment: What does your converter actually look like? As-is this won't compile because of how you've declared the ObservableCollection. What type of OC is it? Is there a reason you are going from a Tuple -> OC of arrays?

Comment: @Danielle, sorry.  Typed the example in NP++.

Comment: Have you tried making sure that the LINQ is evaluated *before* returning from the converter by adding a `.ToList()` to the return statement?

Comment: @ChrisF, the LINQ is evaluated as part of the ctor for `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @gregsdennis - ah of course.

Comment: What does it display without the Converter? I tried your code in a sample project and saw correct Tuple display in an ItemsControl that had no special properties. When adding the converter, I saw all of the parts of the Tuples separated into their own strings and displayed on their own lines as an item in the control.

Comment: @Danielle, yes, as I mentioned, I can't replicate the problem in another app.  The code above works as expected, but it doesn't work in my app.  I get nothing.

Comment: Where did you have defined ItemsTemplate. Can you check the behavior with ListBox to see if any child item appears?

Comment: @user1672994, they're strings.  I don't need a template.  WPF uses TextBlock by default.